# OptaPlanner solution inheritance with generics causes error

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, optaplanner

I have an abstract generic "Foo" solution class, which my specific implementations inherit. This class is generic, and allows for the implementing class to define their specific PlanningEntity, which extends "Bar"

This chokes up optaplanner, which spits out an error like the following:

The solutionProperty (list) was not cloned as expected. The FieldAccessingSolutionCloner failed to recognize that property's field, probably because its field name is different.

I have tried replacing "EntityType" with the specific implementing class and things seem to work. However, I am trying to extract common functionality to reduce maintenance, and this is preventing me from extracting all of the commonalities.

I have also tried combing through the OptaPlanner documentation. I could not find an example like this.

```java
@PlanningSolution
public abstract class Foo <EntityType extends Bar> implements Solution<HardMediumSoftScore>
{
    protected HardMediumSoftScore score;
    protected ArrayList<EntityType> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    public ArrayList<EntityType> getList()
    {
        return this.list;
    }

    @Override
    public HardMediumSoftScore getScore()
    {
        return this.score;
    }

    public void setScore(HardMediumSoftScore score)
    {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to inherit without optaplanner throwing errors.

Is optaplanner set up to handle generics / inheritance? I am using 6.5, is there a newer release that supports this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `@DeepPlanningClone` annotation on that field.

Also, migrate away from `implements Solution` to `@PlanningSolution`, see *upgrade recipe* on optaplanner.org.

Comment: This did it, thanks! WRT updating its on the radar - thanks for the link though.